# Extracting a fundamental period.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-transform, periodic-functions

There is given sequence 
$$a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},...$$
Where $a_{n}\in\{1,2,...,N\}$ for every natural $n$.

It is also known that this sequence is periodic.

> Find the fundamental period the sequence.

I know that "Discrete Fourier Transform" is usefull. But to apply it to extract "$T$" from equation $a_{n+T}=a_{n}$ ?

Regards.

Comment: Do you have an "oracle" that somehow magically computes the discrete Fourier transform of the series? The reason I ask is that no finite number (no matter how large) of values of such a series definitively gives the period $T$.

Comment: You can't find the period without knowing what sequence you're talking about